# What is the double arrow cursor in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What is the double arrow cursor in Photoshop?  What hotkey switches to it?

I'm getting this cursor by accident while using the brush tool and hitting "step backward".  Surprisingly, Google for "double arrow cursor" just returns a bunch of irrelevant links surprisingly.

Edit: You can get it by holding command + alt on a Mac.  Also when you click on the canvas, it creates a new layer.

Comment: Do you have an image of what the cursor looks like?

Comment: Let me try to screencapture it - it's black arrow overlaying a white arrow

Answer (score 4):

This cursor indicates that you are in "copy" mode which for example: if you hold the combination of keys like you did (ctrl+alt, while using brush tool) over any layer you will automatically copy it and grab it while you can move it around holding keys and releasing to place the copy wherever you want. Hope that helps.